# pop3 mail proxy on linux server

Tags: linux, proxy, imap, pop3

I have an ISP pop3 account and I need to retrieve mails on my server (ubuntu server) to feed an IMAP webmail (roundcube) installed on my server too.

So, I need :
my_ISP_POP3server -> POP3proxy_onMyServer -> IMAPserver_onMyServer -> webmail_onMyServer

My big problem is finding the pop3 mail proxy but if there is a global solution I'm ok ! 
Someone know an easy config solution for my need ?

Thanks !

--- Edit ----

Thanks Alex-hha ! Now I've problems for running everting...

[IMAP server can't read (open) mails using fetchmail, procmail & dovecot](https://serverfault.com/questions/771212/imap-server-cant-read-open-mails-using-fetchmail-procmail-dovecot)

Comment: What about fetchmail? Fetchmail retrieves mail from remote mail servers and forwards it via SMTP. It allows all your system MTA's filtering, forwarding, and aliasing facilities to work just as they would on normal mail.

Comment: I tried fetchmail but config seem to be a little tricky... And the exemples I found weren't about proxy. Maybe I had to retry !